# Self-Vandalism, what is correct action

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks, vandalism

Reviewing low quality posts, I was sent to review this Question

[BASH Combination simple program to get some output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159996/bash-combination-simple-program-to-get-some-output)

Where the user had vandalized their own post by replacing it with

*hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh*

I ***rolled back*** and ***flagged***.

**This leaves me wondering:**

- Is there a more official action to take?
- Are there ways or reasons to lock a post in a way that OP cannot change it?
- Should there be?
- or is ***rolling back*** and ***flagging*** the correct route?

Comment: Rollback and flag is the way to go. Repeated vandalism results in a ban (that is, if a moderator is made aware of it).

Comment: Hmm... seems someone won't be able to do this for a week or so, now.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I see. Then flagging is enough!

Comment: Yes, that usually works great. This post and an auto flag from all the edits sped things up, but thanks for looking out for that!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Is there a more official action to take?

Rolling it back, like you did. Usually an OP will do that because they've either found their answer or think their question is "stupid" for lack of a better term, and are unable to delete it because of other answers on the question. There's not really any reason to flag a one-time occurrence, though. Vandalism of multiple posts, or continued rollbacks on the same post, will be automatically flagged for moderator attention by the Community user and action will be taken.

> Are there ways or reasons to lock a post in a way that OP cannot change it?

Moderators *can* lock a question to prevent inappropriate editing, but that also has its own side effects, like preventing additional answers from being posted, as well as preventing further voting. We reserve that action for only more extreme cases.

Comment: Why isn't there support for just locking editing?

Comment: @ColeJohnson It's been suggested before, but the problem with only locking a certain aspect of a post is that it makes the other aspects unfair. For example, it's not really fair that a post can continue to be downvoted but the user is not allowed to edit and improve it. You have to lock everything or nothing at all.